# Why are there still many people after the first Infinite Tsukuyomi?

Tags: naruto

On *Naruto Shippuden* episode 461, after Kaguya cast the Infinite Tsukuyomi and her twin children grew up, they still live with people. I don't understand why there are still so many people.

Supposedly, the Infinite Tsukuyomi's light can pass through anything and doesn't have a shadow. So everyone will just get affected and sleep for eternity just like the second Infinite Tsukuyomi that Madara cast.

Why are there still many people after the first Infinite Tsukuyomi?

Comment: I think it's because Haguromo and Hagurama sealed her away. They had the rinnegan so they were not affected.

Comment: @SujalMotagi you mean Hagoromo and Hamura. And OP is referring to the time when Kaguya cast the Infinite Tsukuyomi and revived some people, before the Otsutsuki brothers were born.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin Oh yeah, I meant Hagoromo and Hamura. Well I was not sure, that's why I said 'I think'.

Comment: Before they sealed Kaguya, they are already living with people. And who the heck is Hagurama.. @SujalMotagi

Comment: @EroSɘnnin yeah, is that your answer? i guess thats it

Comment: I'll put in a proper answer with the chapter numbers.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin Reminder for the above comment.

Answer (score 3):

Alright so in S9 Ep 461 the toad Gamamaru tells the Six Paths Brothers that the Memory Stone, in The Land of the Toads, records everything that happens on the surface world.(And yes this does mean that Mt. Myōboku is underground. Better said a different dimension within the earth.) The Stone shows Kayuga casting the Infinite Tsukuyomi and everyone being enveloped by the Divine Tree, which fell from space by the way along with Kayuga, Gamamaru then says that she released some humans and wiped their memories to create a healthy amount of sacrifices for The Divine Tree to steal Nature Energy the strongest force. Hope this helps! Sorry that it’s really late!

Answer (score 1):

Because only a few people actually had chakra, the infinite tsukuyomi is still a genjutsu so, and genjutsu works by disrupting the flow of chakra, so people who didn't have chakra wasn't affected

Comment: That's actually a very interesting answer.

Comment: I think that's correct